# Running non position independent executable on ASLR system

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gcc, aslr

`ASLR` is active on my machine:

```
$ cat /proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space
2

$ ldd prog.out 
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffcf0cf000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fed500e9000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fed504b3000)

$ ldd prog.out
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffc0e3d5000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f6aa4ba1000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f6aa4f6b000)
```

So it seems/means that `gcc` uses `pie` by default, as every executable I'm building with simple `gcc -o prog.out some_source.c` will be able to run in different addresses by default.

But, output of `gcc -v` does not contain any default `pie` configuration:

```
$ gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 4.9.3-13ubuntu2' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.9/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,c++,java,go,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-4.9 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.9 --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-plugin --with-system-zlib --disable-browser-plugin --enable-java-awt=gtk --enable-gtk-cairo --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.9-amd64/jre --enable-java-home --with-jvm-root-dir=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.9-amd64 --with-jvm-jar-dir=/usr/lib/jvm-exports/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.9-amd64 --with-arch-directory=amd64 --with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/eclipse-ecj.jar --enable-objc-gc --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.9.3 (Ubuntu 4.9.3-13ubuntu2)
```

and also using `file` on `prog.out` gives file type of `ELF 64-bit LSB executable` instead of `ELF 64-bit LSB shared object` (as should be for position independent executables as well as shared objects):

```
$ file prog.out
prog.out: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=78586a68c607677ba529d5b0952232dab927eb9e, not stripped
```

So by looking at `gcc` default flags and the file type, it seems as if the executable is non `pie` but it is able to be executed on `ASLR` system, which is not possible, so what am I missing here?

My machine:

```
$ uname -a
Linux ssg-dev-vb 4.13.0-41-generic #46~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu May 3 10:06:43 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: **Why** do you need an non-PIE, but dynamically linked, ELF executable (on a system where most of them are)? That reason should go into your question (which seems some [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/)...). So please **edit your question** to improve it, motivate it and give more context

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I do not need anything, I am trying to understand the combination of `ASLR` and (allegedly) non `pie` executable as such executable cannot actually run on `ASLR` system

Comment: But a PIE ELF executable is *not* described as a shared object by `file`

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch guides online says otherwise, and also what about the `gcc` flags that lack the default `pie`?

Comment: Run twice `cat /proc/self/maps` on your machine.You'll see that ASLR works even on the executable binary, which is mapped on different addresses from one run to the next. ASLR is also relevant for [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I think you did not understand my problem. I know ASLR is working, and it means that gcc compiles executables with pie by default, BUT- according to gcc default flags it seems that gcc is actually NOT compiling with pie by default

Comment: PIE is probably also an `ld` flag. Look into the relevant `ld` scripts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The executable is position-dependent (and not shown in the `ldd`) output.  The libraries are still position-independent and mapped at a random start address by the kernel.  To disable that, you'd need to run the program under `setarch x86_64 -R` or `gdb` (which disables randomization to help with reproducibility during debugging).

Comment: but ASLR is active. If executable is position-dependent how can it execute with ASLR ?

Comment: The kernel loads the main executable, and it simply picks a fixed address for it. And even with ASLR, applications can pick fixed addresses with `mmap` because the kernel still follows the address hint (if possible). And of course, there is also `MAP_FIXED`.